# Ionic conditional class css

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using Ionic3, and have:

```
<span class="char-left">{{REVIEW_MAX_LENGTH-ratingModel.review.length}} characters left</span>
```

I would like to conditionally change the `class` value when another value is populated, i.e when `ratingForm.controls.review.length > 0` change the values to `class="char-left-error"`.

I did look at [`ng-class`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34306816/ionic-conditional-text-color), but cannot seem to get it to work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You should take another look at `ng-class`

Comment: if I do `<span ng-class="char-left">`, the class `char-left` is not even applied.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If it's just a single class, you can try with

```
<span class="char-left" [class.char-left-error]="ratingForm.controls.review.length > 0">
```

By using [ngClass](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html) it would look like

```
<span class="char-left" [ngClass]="{'char-left-error' : ratingForm.controls.review.length > 0}">
```