# How to bind Ionic Style property with condition in Angular 7?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic Chip. But, the problem when I want to write color attribute with condition in `[ngStyle]` tag.

> Works Fine

```
<ion-chip color="warning"> ABC Heading </ion-chip>
```

> Problem

```
<ion-chip [ngStyle]="{'color': item.Valid == true ? 'success' : 'warning'}"> {{item.Valid == true ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid'}} </ion-chip>
```

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022439/ionic-conditional-class-css

Comment: Already tried with [ngClass]. But, nothing happened.

Comment: Then I think you need to check your condition i.e. "item.Valid == true" is it correctly working or not?

Comment: Tried without condition? That means hardcoded  value

Comment: <ion-chip [ngClass]="{'color': item.Valid == true ? 'success' :  'warrning'}"> {{item.Valid == true ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid'}} </ion-chip>

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to change the color you can just bind the `[color]` property:

```
 <ion-chip [color]="item.isValid?'success':'warning'"> ABC Heading </ion-chip>
```

Note that using `[ngStyle]` with the color attribute will change the DOM elements colors, meaning the inner text color will change. It is not related to the ionic color attribute

[Here's an example to illustrate](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-vwrwnu?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: But, this way item.isValid is false all the time and warning shows. This is my line of code: <ion-chip [color]="item.isValid == true ? 'success': 'warning'"> {{item.Valid == true ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid'}} </ion-chip>

Comment: I’ve updated the answer with a stackblitz example to show how you can use ngStyle

Comment: It works fine. I understood. But, if I want to use more that one attributes, then I have to write this individually? Such as, [color], [outline] etc. Or, is there any combined way for that?

Comment: Well using ngStyle you’d still have to type each property manually (like background-color, outline, etc...) the only difference is that you type them all in the ngStyle instead of different properties of the ion components (which is even less readable in my opinion)